# Unable to use Google Docs URL invite action in new URL to invite user to a copy of a document

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-docs

I have created a google sheets document that I am wanting to send out to a number of users for them to make copies of, share back with me and then edit themselves.

I am using the largely under documented URL features in google docs (explained [Here](https://learninginhand.com/blog/google-document-url-tricks), [Here](https://blog.toriihq.com/going-pro-with-google-docs-links) and  [Here](https://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/) ), to require the end user to make a copy of the document, with a new title and then automatically invite me as an editor of the document.

Replacing the edit element of the URL allows me to get a user to make a copy of the document and rename it, but when I use the userstoinvite option, when viewed on the end users PC they are not asked to link me back into the document. This does work correctly when I test the link myself, so it could potentially be a permissions issue inside my local network.

I'm using the following format in my URL:

doc-url/copy?&title=DocTitle&userstoinvite="email@email.com"

When the URL is accessed both myself and a end user receive the following copy message as normal

[image: Copy Message]

When the document opens I then receive the message to link another individual (myself) to the document.

[image: Add person link]

When sat with an end user, the document opens, but there is no option to link the document back to me.

The resultant URL for me and the end user is different when the document is opened

- me - edit?userstoinvite="email@email.com"#gid=1779197726
- enduser -edit?#gid=1779197726

I can see the obvious issue is that the email address is not populating in the end users URL, but I cannot see any reason why the URL is being produced separately for myself and the end user, so in theory it should work, but for some reason it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<<insert your document ID>>/copy?&title=DocTitle&userstoinvite=email@email.com`

---

Looking at your question, I think there are a few key differences.

- do NOT include the `gid` reference
- do NOT wrap your email address in quotes.

  - if you have multiple email addresses to invite, separate each by a comma. BUT don't put them in double quotes
  - for example: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<<insert your document ID>>/copy?&title=DocTitle&userstoinvite=email@email.com,email2@email.com`

---

You can test this for yourself by creating a second gmail account and sending the spreadsheet to that user. When the user opens the link:

- they are invited to make a copy of the document
- the document name is automatically changed to the `title` value, AND
- they are invited to share the new spreadsheet with you (as an editor).